# Sort data in .erb file rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

In my rails app I have iterate through discussions as below code.

```
<% @di.each do |d| %>
  //my code goes here
<% end %>
```

This is my application_controller.rb

```
def load_feed_discussions(url:)
@c = session[:council] || ''
res = RestClient.get url, api_token_hash

@di = (JSON.parse(res.body) if res.code == 200)
  rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse
@di = nil
end
```

This is my discussion_controller.rb

```
def index
   # Load Discussions
   load_feed_discussions(url: api_version_root+'/discussions/all?council='+session[:council])
end
```

I want to sort discussion according to the 'updated_date'. How can I do this?

EDIT : here some sample data for @di

> {"id"=>"609b966e-99f1-4606-ab8d-3c99ebb8dc9c", "question"=>"tttest body", "user_id"=>"609b966e-99f1-4606-ab8d-3c99ebb8dc9c", "score_model"=>nil, "council_id"=>"98bc626f-fbef-4b63-9cc9-4f1f2bad6b06", "created_at"=>"2020-04-22T11:41:51.503Z", "updated_date"=>"2020-06-29T03:06:49.155Z", "is_anonymous"=>false, "company_id"=>nil, "topics"=>nil, "was_edited"=>nil, "startup_id"=>nil, "recipients"=>[], "visibility_team"=>"default", "title_line"=>"tttest sub",   "title"=>"Engineer",  "company_logo"=>nil}

Comment: What should `JSON.parse(res.body)` return in the best scenario? A hash, an array?

Comment: So, instead of doing `@di = nil` in the rescue, do `@di = {}`  so you're returning the same object and don't have a NoMethodError. But, are you sure you want a sorted hash? Can you share a sample content of `@di`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma it returns an array not a hash.I checked again

Comment: So, use `@di = []` on the rescue and forget about `order`, use `sort_by` as in the answer. That must do the trick :D.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I am confused. I had below error. Very sorry I am new for the rails. 
 undefined method `updated_date' for #<Hash:0x00007fe20ea6a0e8>

Comment: @SebastianPalma I added sample content

Comment: @SebastianPalma ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends heavily on what's `@di`; if it's an array of objects that respond to `updated_date` then you can use [`Enumerable#sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
<% @di.sort_by(&:updated_date).each do |d| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

If it's an `ActiveRecord_Relation` instance, you can use [`ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#order`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order):

```
<% @di.order(:updated_date).each do |d| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The answer was none of the proposed ones, but `sort_by { |e| e['updated_at'] }.reverse`.

Comment: I am very new for the rails. I edited my question. Can you check it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that @di is an array of responses, you can sort in descending date as follows in the controller...

```
def load_feed_discussions(url:)
  @c = session[:council] || ''
  res = RestClient.get url, api_token_hash
  @di = [] # initialize to empty array in case of res.code != 200 or exception
  @di = JSON.parse(res.body) if res.code == 200
rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse
else
  @di = @di.sort_by{|discussion| discussion['updated_date']}.reverse
end
```

It's not considered good practice to sort data in the view.

Comment: Turczyn This gives oldest data first. How can I have latest first

Comment: Just reverse it.  `@di = @di.sort_by{|discussion| discussion['updated_date']}.reverse` I'll modify answer.